# PostGIS table intersection Query

Tags: postgis, intersection

So I have a table in PostGIS, and each row has a linestring geometry in it. I would like to do a query to return the whole rows of the table that intersect with the linestring along with the position(s) of that intersect.

At the moment I am using;

```
import geopandas as gpd
import psycopg2  # (if it is postgres/postgis)

con = psycopg2.connect(database="your database", user="user", password="password",
    host="your host")

sql = "select geom, x,y,z from your_table which intersects Linestring”

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql,con,geom_col='geom' )
```

I’m a complete beginner to SQL and the resources surround PostGIS `ST_Intersect` aren't so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think this query should work,

```
sql = (
'SELECT geom, x, y, z, ST_Intersection(geom, {1}) '
'FROM your_table '
'WHERE ST_Intersects({1}, geom)'
).format(your_geometry)
```

Now, you don't specify the format of your geometry so you will have to convert it to 
postgis `geometry` somehow. You have a number of functions to read a geometry, like `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`, `ST_GeomFromText`, etc.

`ST_Intersects` returns true if the geometrys share any portion of space [ST_Intersects Doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html)

`ST_Intersection` returns the geometry result of the intersection [ST_Intersection Doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)